# Groovy script assertion behaving strange

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a test case where I have defined some custom properties for just performing an addition operation. Now I want to assert that the result is actually equal to the sum of both inputs. I wrote a groovy script for it to validate and log the two inputs and did a comparison check.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
holder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://tempuri.org/"
def conversionRate = holder.getNodeValue("//ns:AdditionResult")
log.info messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("operand1").toInteger() 
log.info messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("operand2").toInteger() 
log.info conversionRate
log.info messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("operand1").toInteger() + messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("operand2").toInteger() == conversionRate
```

When I execute it logs the following:

```
Sun Mar 13 15:22:53 IST 2016:INFO:122
Sun Mar 13 15:22:53 IST 2016:INFO:12
Sun Mar 13 15:22:53 IST 2016:INFO:134
Sun Mar 13 15:22:53 IST 2016:INFO:false
```

It's giving me *false* instead of *true*. Shouldn't it be *true* instead of *false*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `conversionRate` an integer as well?

```
def i = '122'.toInteger()
def j = '12'.toInteger()
def rate = '134'
println i + j == rate
println i + j == rate.toInteger()
```